# I can't use CSS code in HTML doc?

Tags: html, css

I am super new to HTML and CSS and I ran into a problem when I try to link CSS code in HTML. The code doesn't show the background color like it should. HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
     <body>
       <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
     <body>
   </html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
background: #999;
}
```

I have them both in the same folder. I am lost and confused so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: They're in the same folder? Maybe you should use `href="main.css"` then instead of `href="styles/main.css"`?

Comment: That worked! I was following a tutorial and they did that for some reason.

Comment: Not maybe SURE !!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use href="main.css"
By using styles/ the browser searches for a folder called styles in the same folders and can't find it so no CSS will be applied

Answer (score 3):

CSS files should be included in the head section. If you have them in the same folder you need to change the href aswell.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
<body>

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: In HTML5 it's ok to place styles in the `<body>` (not to say you should).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the link element to head tag instead of body tag.